# grouping with dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading data analysis in python by Wes McKinney

Grouping information may exist in a form other than an array. Let’s consider another
example DataFrame:

```
In [38]: people = DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 5),
....: columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
....: index=['Joe', 'Steve', 'Wes', 'Jim', 'Travis'])

In [39]: people.ix[2:3, ['b', 'c']] = np.nan # Add a few NA values
```

Now, suppose I have a group correspondence for the columns and want to sum together
the columns by group:

```
In [41]: mapping = {'a': 'red', 'b': 'red', 'c': 'blue',
               ....: 'd': 'blue', 'e': 'red', 'f' : 'orange'}
```

Now, you could easily construct an array from this dict to pass to groupby, but instead
we can just pass the dict:

```
In [42]: by_column = people.groupby(mapping, axis=1)
```

My question is what does author mean by "easily construct an array from this dict to pass to groupby".

Another question is how do we construct list from dict and pass to array and get the same result as below

```
by_column = people.groupby(mapping, axis=1)
```

Kindly explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dict `mapping` is being used to map the column names of `people` to colors for grouping. As an alternative to passing this map to `groupby`, we can perform this step separately, with

```
people.columns = [mapping[col] for col in people.columns]
```

using a list comprehension, or

```
people.columns = people.columns.to_series().map(mapping)
```

to get a similar effect with pandas methods

Aside – it appears that `map` for pandas `Index` objects can't take dictionaries yet, as of 0.20.2, necessitating the `to_series()` if going this route.

and then `groupby` the columns

```
by_column2 = people.groupby(people.columns, axis=1)
```

Giving the same result. Ex:

```
In [11]: by_column.sum()
Out[11]: 
            blue       red
Joe     0.548220  1.744519
Steve  -2.056899  0.907479
Wes     0.093676 -2.145836
Jim     1.782462  0.715873
Travis -0.066277 -2.286108

In [12]: by_column2.sum()
Out[12]: 
            blue       red
Joe     0.548220  1.744519
Steve  -2.056899  0.907479
Wes     0.093676 -2.145836
Jim     1.782462  0.715873
Travis -0.066277 -2.286108
```

I think that should cover question 2, though let me know if that wasn't where you aimed to take this. I would guess for question 1 that the author just meant this, the above, is easy to do, taking all of an extra line on top of the method being demonstrated.